# React not loading image

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to make my component load an image.
I have the following structure:

```
src/components/menu/myFile.js
src/images/logo.png
```

Here is myFile.js where I try to load the logo.png

```
const myFile = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <header class="header_main">
            <section class="container">
                <section class="row">
                    <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <figure class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="../../images/logo.png"  alt=""/></a></figure>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <ul class="nav_main pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </header>
    </Aux>
);
```

It is not loading the logo.png and when I check it in the browser using firebug, it says "Could not load the image"

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with react, your server is not hosting the image properly

Comment: do you use create-react-app? It is up to webpack to bundle assets. In most cases, you have to import image by relative path, to get the actual path after bundling:
`import logoPath from '../../images/logo.png'`

Comment: Yes, I used ```npx create-react-app my-app```. After importing the logoPath, how can I insert it in my img src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import logo from "../../images/logo.png"
```

Inside image

```
<img src={logo} />
```

this will work

Comment: If I have multiple images, can I use ```import Images from "../../images"``` Then, ```src={Images.logo.png}``` ?

Comment: For people watching in future Yes of course!
Like this 
`const Images = {
image1:"image_url1",
image2:"image_url2"
...
}`

on your comp
`import Images from "../path-of-that-const" `

`<img src={Images.image1} />`

Answer (score 1):

First Import the image like:

```
import logo from '../../images/logo.png';
```

then plug it in like :

```
<img src={logo} />
```